# Windows Message for User Locking Screen

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, message, logout

I'm working with old-school windows programming in C++, and I need to capture an event in my WndProc which indicates that the user has logged off or locked the screen.

**update**  (thanks David Hefernan) I've searched everywhere, but the only thing I've found is the WM_ENDSESSION message - which does not handle screen lock events.

Anyone know what how this is done?  I need to apply it to Windows 2000 through Windows XP flavors.

Comment: `WM_ENDSESSION` lParam includes `ENDSESSION_LOGOFF` when it's a log off rather than a shutdown

Comment: @David: Unbelievable (frustration).  Thank you for spotting that.  Now I just need to figure out why my app is not reacting to WM_ENDESSION, not matter what I do - it is as if my app is not receiving it at all.

Comment: Brent, simply call WTSRegisterSessionNotification to receive the relevant messages.

Comment: @Joe: I'd love to try it, if (1) the remote desktop API applies even when not "using" remote desktop and (2) if someone will give the secret of which header files must be included to have access to the API (do you?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to [register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841%28VS.85%29.aspx) for the [`WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383828%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and respond to it in your WndProc.

According to the documentation of `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE`, the minimum supported OS is XP. Now, the since Windows 2000 is no longer supported, the documentation often says XP is the minumum when in fact the functionality is available on earlier versions.  In this case, a quick web search suggests that you may be disappointed.

To be notified about *session logoff* (rather then the screen lock), you should be able to use the `lParam` value of the [`WM_ENDSESSION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376889%28VS.85%29.aspx) message.  Look for the presence of the `ENDSESSION_LOGOFF` flag.

Comment: When you say "registering," do you mean an API call like "RegisterWindowMessage()" `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644947.aspx`? Or do you simply mean I should add it to my WndProc?

Comment: @Brent Notice that register is a link (to WTSRegisterSessionNotification). Follow the link! I'm pretty sure that you can't use `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE` on Win2k.