# Detect when user locks/unlocks screen in Windows 7 with Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-2009

How to detect when the user locks/unlocks the screen in Windows 7?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44980/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-if-my-workstation-is-locked) which has an answer for C#, but I'd like to use it in Delphi 2009. I'd guess there is some windows message (like [these](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/SendMessageList.htm)) which could do the work. This is the code I tried, but it didn't work:

```
const
  NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS = 1;
  {$EXTERNALSYM NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS}
  NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION = 0;
  {$EXTERNALSYM NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION}

type

TfrmAlisson = class(TForm)
  lbl2: TLabel;
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
public
  FLockedCount: Integer;
  procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  function WTSRegisterSessionNotification(hWnd: HWND; dwFlags: DWORD): bool; stdcall;
  function WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification(hWND: HWND): bool; stdcall;
end;

implementation

uses
  // my impl uses here

procedure TfrmAlisson.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (WTSRegisterSessionNotification(Handle, NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION)) then
    ShowMessage('Nice')
  else
  begin
    lastError := GetLastError;
    ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(lastError));
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmAlisson.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification(Handle);
end;

procedure TfrmAlisson.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE:
      begin
        if Message.wParam = WTS_SESSION_LOCK then
        begin
          Inc(FLockedCount);
        end;
        if Message.wParam = WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK then
        begin
          lbl2.Caption := 'Session was locked ' +
          IntToStr(FLockedCount) + ' times.';
        end;
      end;
  end;
  inherited;
end;

function TfrmAlisson.WTSRegisterSessionNotification(hWnd: HWND; dwFlags: DWORD): bool;
  external 'wtsapi32.dll' Name 'WTSRegisterSessionNotification';

function TfrmAlisson.WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification(hWND: HWND): bool;
  external 'wtsapi32.dll' Name 'WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification';
```

When `FormCreate` executes, `WTSRegisterSessionNotification` returns `false` and the last OS error returns **Invalid Parameter**.

Comment: call [WTSRegisterSessionNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841(VS.85).aspx) and you got [WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198210/windows-message-for-user-locking-screen?rq=1) messages. when `wParam` is `WTS_SESSION_LOCK` or `WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK` your case

Comment: @RbMm thanks, I'm gonna read and tell you if I manage to achieve it.

Comment: @RbMm: that should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - really this duplicate - for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/5198312/6401656

Comment: @RbMm: then you should have voted to close this question as a duplicate

Comment: @RemyLebeau I edited the question. I tried implementing it, but I'm not familiar with winapi, so I don't know if I did something wrong. When I call `WTSRegisterSessionNotification`, it returns **false** and if I get last OS error, it returns **invalid parameter** (in portuguese, in my case).

Comment: You must not pass a VCL window handle. They can be recreated. Use AllocateHWnd. Or the application window.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: there is nothing wrong with using a VCL window handle, as long as you account for recreation, in this case by overriding the Form's `CreateWnd()` method.

Comment: Which this code doesn't do, does it. And there's a window during recreation where you aren't listening. So yes, it is wrong to use a VCL window.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for your advice, it's important pointing everything that could fail. My code is now allocating a dedicated window, as the code suggested by Remy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code does not work because you did not implement it correctly.

You are not declaring `WTSRegisterSessionNotification()` and `WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification()` correctly.

Also, you are not accounting for the possibility of the VCL ever recreating the Form's window dynamically during the Form object's lifetime.  So, even if `WTSRegisterSessionNotification()` were successful, you can lose your registration and not realize it.

Try this instead:

```
interface

uses
  ...;

type
  TfrmAlisson = class(TForm)
    lbl2: TLabel;
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
    procedure DestroyWindowHandle; override;
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  public
    LockedCount: Integer;
  end;

implementation

const
  NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION = $0;
  NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS = $1;

function WTSRegisterSessionNotification(hWnd: HWND; dwFlags: DWORD): Boolean; stdcall; external 'wtsapi32.dll' name 'WTSRegisterSessionNotification';
function WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification(hWnd: HWND): Boolean; stdcall; external 'wtsapi32.dll' name 'WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification';

procedure TfrmAlisson.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  if not WTSRegisterSessionNotification(Handle, NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;

procedure TfrmAlisson.DestroyWindowHandle;
begin
  WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification(Handle);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TfrmAlisson.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE then
  begin
    case Message.wParam of
      WTS_SESSION_LOCK: begin
        Inc(LockedCount);
      end;
      WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK: begin
        lbl2.Caption := Format('Session was locked %d times.', [LockedCount]);
      end;
    end;
  end;
  inherited;
end;

end.
```

---

That being said, consider writing the code to not rely on the VCL's window recreation behavior.  You can allocate a dedicated window for monitoring the session changes:

```
interface

uses
  ...;

type
  TfrmAlisson = class(TForm)
    lbl2: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    SessionWnd: HWND;
    procedure SessionWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
  public
    LockedCount: Integer;
  end;

implementation

const
  NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION = $0;
  NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS = $1;

function WTSRegisterSessionNotification(hWnd: HWND; dwFlags: DWORD): Boolean; stdcall; external 'wtsapi32.dll' name 'WTSRegisterSessionNotification';
function WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification(hWnd: HWND): Boolean; stdcall; external 'wtsapi32.dll' name 'WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification';

procedure TfrmAlisson.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SessionWnd := AllocateHWnd(SessionWndProc);
  if not WTSRegisterSessionNotification(SessionWnd, NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;

procedure TfrmAlisson.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if SessionWnd <> 0 then
  begin
    WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification(SessionWnd);
    DeallocateHWnd(SessionWnd);
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmAlisson.SessionWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE then
  begin
    case Message.wParam of
      WTS_SESSION_LOCK: begin
        Inc(LockedCount);
      end;
      WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK: begin
        lbl2.Caption := Format('Session was locked %d times.', [LockedCount]);
      end;
    end;
  end;

  Message.Result := DefWindowProc(SessionWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
end;

end.
```

Comment: I'm receiving `undeclared identifier: WTSRegisterSessionNotification`. I added `Windows` to interface uses. I forgot to mention I'm compiling with Windows 10, even though the application will be ran by users with Windows 7.

Comment: I redeclared it, following [this sample](https://github.com/magicmonty/delphi-code-coverage/blob/master/3rdParty/JWAPI/jwapi2.2a/Win32API/JwaWtsApi32.pas), and it worked with your sample. The only thing I noted is `DestroyWnd` is not called when I'm debugging and close the application (maybe this is called after the process is detached from debugger).

Comment: @Alisson: my bad, the WTS functions were added to the `Windows` unit in XE2. As for `DestroyWnd()`, it is only called when the window is destroyed while the Form remains alive. The VCL bypasses `DestroyWnd` during the Form's destruction. I have updated my answer to account for these.

Comment: It worked nicely, thank you so much. I changed my code to allocate a dedicated window like suggested.

Comment: FWIW, in `CreateWnd` and `DestroyWindowHandle`, it is idiomatic to use `WindowHandle` rather than `Handle`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: they are the same thing in those contexts. They both return `FHandle`. The only difference is `Handle` allocates `FHandle` if zero, `WindowHande` doesn't. In those contexts, `FHandle` is never zero. And I rarely ever see anyone use `WindowHandle` in those contexts. Either one works.