# Catch LockScreen event in Windows from C++ console program

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, event-handling, lockscreen

In Windows 10, I have a C++ console program which I want to terminate if the screen locks due to either a lock screen setting or it is locked manually by the user.

The program is running at all times but if the screen gets locked, I want to terminate it. Therefore I want to catch the event and then handle the event to exit the program.

How do I catch such event?

Comment: Does this answer your question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198210/windows-message-for-user-locking-screen

Comment: @PepijnKramer. Looks like that's for Window processes but it's in the right direction.

Comment: I think you will have to create a thread with a message loop on it to receive that signal. Which you then can use in your console application (or very bluntly, let the thread with the messageloop terminate the process if that's safe)